# Is there a way to handle `abi.decode` errors?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, require, custom-errors, revert

I am trying to decode a bytes value, and while writing tests, I was trying to pass invalid values to force an error.
Although I get the error `missing revert data in call exception`, I cannot find a way to revert with a custom error/string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While writing the question, I was able to find a solution.
ATTOW this is already a feature request. See [issue-10381](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/10381) and [issue-10933](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/10933) on github. Thankfully one of the core members mentioned in this [comment](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/10381#issuecomment-1285986476) that this feature is on the roadmap.

If you're reading this in the future, please leave an updated answer.